# Trigonometric equation with two variables

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find solutions of the following equation
\begin{equation}
4\cos(x) + 5\cos (x+y)=5
\end{equation}
and the best I’ve managed so far is to express $y$ in terms of $x$

$y= \pm\arccos\biggl(1-\frac{4\cos(x)}{5}\biggr) - x + 2\pi n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Is there a way to simplify this further?

My thinking is that since I have a single equation but two unknown variables, I cannot define a finite set of solutions. But how can I define the range for which $x$ exists?

Comment: substitute $z=x+y$.

Comment: I'd start by expanding $cos(x+y)$

Comment: @Damascuz, I don't think that (expansion) will help

Comment: Then divide by 5: $1-4/5cos(x)=cos(z)$. This implies that $cos(x)\ge 0, cos(z)\ge 0.$ This gives you a range for $x$ and $z=x+y$.

Comment: It'll give range . Not solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested: substitute $z=x+y$ and divide by 5:

$$1-4/5\cos x=\cos z.$$

Since $|\cos z|\le 1$, you get $\cos x\ge 0$. This gives $$-\pi/2+2\pi k\le x\le \pi/2+2\pi k $$ for every integer $k$. Each such $x$ determines a $z$ and a $y$.